# Vuetify nested datatable columns width problem

Tags: html, css, vue.js, datatable, vuetify.js

You can see the example on **[CodePen](https://codepen.io/sshiling/pen/gNzVvz)**.

I have a vuetify data table and nested data tables in it. 
You can open the nested table by click on the row item id.

If you select some row by check checkbox - the additional input field will appear.

The problem is that the outer table columns width and inner table columns width are different, but I need the data in the inner table right below the data of the outer table.

**I tried:** 
1. To setup the width of the same columns for headers. 
2. To use just one header data for both tables.

If I show header and checkboxes in the inner table it looks better, 
 but I don't need them in the inner table.

This piece of code is just for passing StackOverflow validation.
The whole example is on CodePen.

```
 <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-layout>
        <v-data-table>
            <v-model>
                <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
```

Comment: Can you explain this a bit clearer `The problem is that the outer table columns width and inner table columns width are different, but I need the data in the inner table right below the data of the outer table.`

Comment: I mean, columns same width. It should be just like one table with nested rows. http://i.shotnes.com/u/2778/0703/screenshot_16329.png

Comment: I mean, I don't know how to align inner data:
http://i.shotnes.com/u/2778/0703/screenshot_20319.png

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Сolleague helped me with this question.
The solution is to use additional  with additional logic instead of adding an additional table. It works perfectly in v-data-table.

Comment: So... what was the solution?